# Azure functions in sub folders

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to group your azure functions into subfolders. It seems like the location of your function.json needs to be

```
/{functionName}/function.json
```

I'd like to have something like this

```
/{category}/{functionName}/function.json
```

When i try this though the function is not detected

Comment: Feature Request: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1240

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the location of `function.json`.

However, you could use the `scriptFile` property of `function.json` to refer to your function code files in another location.

Comment: Can you store all your function.json in the same folder?

Comment: never mind, silly question because they will all be the same file name, i assume they have to be called function.json to be detected. maybe storing functions.json in one project and code implementation in another might be the way to go.

Comment: For now i think i'll just use a naming convention that somewhat groups functions. Something like /{category}-{functionName}/function.json